# Swipeable listview Not Autoclosing

Tags: react-native

Using React v0.31.  The Swipeable listview I implemented does not have autoclosing, which is advertised in the source code.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

```
_renderQuickActionButtons: function(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
  return (<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',  }}>
    <View style={{flex:1}} />
    <View style={{width: 100, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}/>
  </View>);
```

},

```
 <SwipeableListView
    scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
    style={{backgroundColor: '#2c2e39'}}
    dataSource={this.state.ds}
    renderRow={this._renderRow}
    maxSwipeDistance={100}
    renderQuickActions={this._renderQuickActionButtons}
    renderSeparator={(s1,r1,_) => <View key={r1} style={{flex: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#2c2e39',}} />}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Just added it.

Answer (score 0):

below snippet is from the SwipeableListView class

```
    <SwipeableListView ....>            
      isOpen={rowData.id === this.props.dataSource.getOpenRowID()}
    </SwipeableListView>
```

the criteria to open/close the row or (Autoclose row) is based on the id, so make sure the array you are passing has **id** field in it